# T-SQL PATINDEX -1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, patindex, charindex

this is my first post here and i'm also a newby in development.
In any case.. my problem is:

sql statement:

```
SELECT left(clienti.SedeLegaleIndirizzo, patindex('%[0-9]%',clienti.SedeLegaleIndirizzo))
AS indirizzo from Clienti
```

`clienti.SedeLegaleIndirizzo` is `clienti` table and `SedeLegaleIndirizzo`is the column with the address including streen and number.
I want to separate street from number but with my statement i get the street with the first number. As i know from charindex i can add -1 to the last parameter but the problem is that it returns me this error if i put that parameter with patindex:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

I'm using patindex and not charindex cause i'm searching a number...

What is anybody's suggestion?

Comment: What you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me where you are placing the `-1` but it looks you are doing this:

```
SELECT left(clienti.SedeLegaleIndirizzo,
        patindex('%[0-9]%', clienti.SedeLegaleIndirizzo)-1)
```

This will give an issue when the number is not found, because then `patindex()` gives `0` and `0-1=-1`. You can't have a `left()` with length `-1`. My solution in these cases is this:

```
SELECT left(SedeLegaleIndirizzo,
        isnull(nullif(patindex('%[0-9]%', SedeLegaleIndirizzo)-1, -1), 0))
```

This ensures that if the number is not found, in stead of trying to do `left(SedeLegaleIndirizzo, -1)` the code will result in `left(SedeLegaleIndirizzo, 0)` and simply give an empty string.

Comment: Happy to help. If my answer worked for you, could you click to accept it? It helps me and the website :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is most likely due to rows without numbers which would make the result of `patindex(...) -1` negative.

One solution is to exclude those rows:

```
SELECT LEFT(clienti.SedeLegaleIndirizzo, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',clienti.SedeLegaleIndirizzo) - 1) 
AS indirizzo FROM Clienti
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',clienti.SedeLegaleIndirizzo) > 0
```